# Postgresql: Match complete word contained in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query as:

```
select id 
from events 
where description is not null 
  and (name ilike any (query_arr) 
       or description ilike any (query_arr) 
       or additional_info ilike any (query_arr) 
       or venue_name ilike any (query_arr) 
       or other_category ilike any (query_arr) 
       or eventful_category ilike any (query_arr) )
```

And **query_arr** is:

```
{'%Tomato%','%Potato%','%Pines%'}
```

But now I need to match the complete word instead of `ilike` `%` sign, since it fails for a case where if the description is 'Porcupines are rodentian mammals' then the **query_arr** word '**pines**' gets matched which is incorrect.

So I need to match the complete word itself any where in the table columns being queried.

Comment: It's looks like you need [FTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev can u provide an example for same

Comment: you can just add spaces around searchwords, like ` select 'Porcupines are rodentian mammals' ~* ' pines ';` instead of ` select 'Porcupines are rodentian mammals' ~* 'pines';`

Comment: `field ~* any(array['\mTomato\M','\mPotato\M','\mPines\M'])`. But FTS looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

FTS - is a large and complex subject. Don't use my example as is.

```
select id from events where to_tsquery('Tomato Potato Pines') @@ to_tsvector(events::text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use this syntax in PostgreSql

```
~*ANY('{query_arr}'::text[])
```

Your Query Should be like this

```
select id from events where description is not null and (name ~*ANY('{query_arr}'::text[]) or description ~*ANY('{query_arr}'::text[]) or additional_info ~*ANY('{query_arr}'::text[]) or venue_name ~*ANY('{query_arr}'::text[]) or other_category ~*ANY('{query_arr}'::text[]) or eventful_category ~*ANY('{query_arr}'::text[])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case changing

`{'%Tomato%','%Potato%','%Pines%'}`

to

`{'% Tomato %','% Potato %','% Pines %'}`

should be enough?..